# EKS Fargate Fluent-Bit multiple Outputs

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-fargate, fluent-bit

I'm running a K8 cluster on Fargate and using FluentBit to send logs to cloudwatch
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-logging.html#fargate-logging-troubleshooting

I'm able to send all logs to a cloudwatch group with this configMap

```
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: aws-observability
  labels:
    aws-observability: enabled
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: aws-logging
  namespace: aws-observability
data:
  output.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name cloudwatch
        Match /var/log/1.log
        region us-east-1
        log_group_name fluent-bit-cloudwatch
        log_stream_prefix from-fluent-bit-
        auto_create_group true
```

Fargate Logging does not support INPUT in fluentBit, only OUTPUT, FILTER, and PARSER

Is it possible to use multiple outputs to send logs from one path to a specific cloudwatch group

something like:

```
[OUTPUT]
        Name cloudwatch
        Match /var/log/1.log
        region us-east-1
        log_group_name fluent-bit-cloudwatch
        log_stream_prefix from-fluent-bit-
        auto_create_group true
    [OUTPUT]
        Name cloudwatch
        Match /var/log/2.log
        region us-east-1
        log_group_name fluent-bit-cloudwatch_2
        log_stream_prefix from-fluent-bit-
        auto_create_group true
```

Where logs from `/var/log/1.log` would go to fluent-bit-cloudwatch cloudwatch group

and logs from `/var/log/2.log` would go to  fluent-bit-cloudwatch_2 cloudwatch group

Comment: Got the same thought, any new on this?